# Customize ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, kotlin

I'm working on a ListView:

I just want to simple edit some things in the design of my listview, as changing the size of the text, center it, etc.

I have read that since I'm using the "SIMPLE_LIST_ITEM_1", I can not edit it like I want to.

I have made a research and found out that I need to create my own layout of the list I want to use. So I did it, and created a layout called listview.xml like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvlist1"
            android:layout_width="263dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:gravity="top|center" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So once I defined the layout I wanted to use, I tried it by replacing the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with `android.R.layout.listview`, but as I was expecting it didn't work.

I tried to create some other customed listviews I found in tutorials, but when testing the filter, it closes the app.

All that I need is to change the size of the text and to center it.

This is my original code:

```
val animalsnames = arrayOf("cat","dog", "mouse", "parrot", "lion", "panda")
internal lateinit var animalsadapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

val list = findViewById(R.id.list1) as ListView
animalsadapter = ArrayAdapter(
    this@MainActivity,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    animalsnames)
list.adapter = animalsadapter
```

This is the conditional for selected position item:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
    when (animalsnames.indexOfFirst { it == animalsadapter.getItem(i) }) {
        0 -> {
            webView.loadUrl("https://cat.com")
            telefono.text = "phonecat"
            webView2.loadUrl("http://cat2.com")
        }

        1 -> {
            webView.loadUrl("http://dog.com")
            telefono.text = "phonedog"
            webView2.loadUrl("https://dog2.com")
        }

        2 -> {
            webView.loadUrl("https://mouse.com")
            telefono.text = "mousephone"
            webView2.loadUrl("http://mouse2.com")
        }
```

This is the edit tect I'm using as filter:

```
    var et_search = findViewById(R.id.e_buscar) as EditText

    et_search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            animalsadapter.filter.filter(s)

        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.R.*` is the import for the R class in the `android` package. Replace it with `R.layout.listview.xml`, or alternatively `com.your.package.R.layout.listview.xml` depending on your imports.

Comment: thanks for your help, I did what you suggested and it just closes my app. instead of load the list with the proper layout

Comment: Find the stacktrace